# Convert LUT formats

Tags: software-recommendation, conversion, nuke, lut

Is there a reliable and somewhat user-friendly way to convert between different LUT formats? I have been searching for a way and find pretty much nothing.

My specific problem at hand is that I have .csp LUT created in Nuke and I would like to apply it directly in my NLE (Premiere or possibly Resolve), however no software I have at hand supports .csp format. I assume it should not be that hard to convert between LUT formats, but it seems like there is almost no software capable of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

YOu could take a look here:
http://opensource.mikrosimage.eu/ColorPipe-tools/LUTLab/LUT_to_LUT/

But this may not give you 100% color accuracy